# Promise fulfill after each loop complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

```
promise.each(function(obj){
    obj.doIntensiveWork()
    .then(function(){
        console.log("I AM FIRST")
    })
})
.then(function(){
    console.log("I AM SECOND")
})
```

let's say `doIntensiveWork()` takes quite some time to fulfill. **"I AM SECOND"** would be logged before **"I AM FIRST"**, since `each` is resolved as `doIntensiveWork()` is called (but not fulfilled) on every obj. Is that correct?

If yes, how can I invert this to make sure **"I AM SECOND"** gets logged **only once** and after the last **"I AM FIRST"** log? I am using the [**Bluebird API**](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md)

Comment: what is in the `promise` var ? an array of promises is that correct ?

Comment: it is a promise that holds a collection of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that each does not wait for the intensiveWork to be finished. You can 'join' all the intensive work by using the `map` function (do not forget the `return`)

```
promise.map(function(obj){
    return obj.doIntensiveWork()
    .then(function(){
        console.log("I AM FIRST")
    })
})
.then(function(){
    console.log("I AM SECOND")
})
```